# How to load assets from folders contained in Resources in a built project - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resources, runtime, assets

I have in my `Resources` folder other folders that each of these contains one or more sprite sheets:

[image]

In order to use these sprites, I use a method that reads this folders structure and saves its contents in a `Dictionary<string, List<Sprite[]>>` where `string` is accessory's name and `List<Sprite[]>` is list of sprite arrays.

To get these sprite arrays I use `Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(spriteToLoad)` where `spriteToLoad` is relative path to exact file (e.g `M4A1/Barrel/Normal_barrels`).

To iterate through these folder I used `DirectoryInfo` in this way:

```
    // Dictionary to store for each accessory its sprite arrays
    weaponAccessories = new Dictionary<string, List<Sprite[]>>();       

    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"Assets\\Resources\\" + weaponName);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirs)
    {
        // Store every list of sprites present in this dir
        List<Sprite[]> sprites = new List<Sprite[]>();

        // Searching for sprite sheets inside this dir
        FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();

        foreach (FileInfo file in file)
        {
            // Formatting path
            var spritesToLoad = weaponName + "/" + dir.Name + "/" file.Name.Replace(".png", "");
            
            // Adding these sprites into sprite arrays for this dir (accessory)
            sprites.Add(Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>(spritesToLoad));
        }
        
        // Add <dir, list of sprite arrays> key-value couple into dictionary
        weaponAccessories.Add(dir.Name, sprites);
     }
```

My solution works fine in play mode because I can directly access to `Resources` and its sub folders iterating on them but when I build the project no sprite is loaded because I can no longer refer to sprite sheet's relative path. The reason is because in the build folder `Resources` folder doesn't exists.

How can I access to this assets in runtime ?

There is a way to access inner `Resources`'s folder during runtime or I need to achieve this in another way ?

Comment: You might consider writing an editor script that you can run manually or at build time that enumerates all of the resources you need to manually load and stores the paths in a scriptable object. You can then use that list to find what is available and load it.

Comment: You can use Application.dataPath which points toward the application in any target platform from where you can access Resources folder.